# Code to read txt files and store in a python dataframe. Some files are not read and give NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While reading txt files from folders, some files return NaN while the actual files are not blank.
Unable to figure out why those files are being left out.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def get_transcripts(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as t:
            text = t.read()
            return text
    except:
        print(file_path)


# parent directory path
path = 'D:\\Urja\\Data_Analytics_project\\NPR_Podcasts\\NPR_Podcasts\\'

# dataframe to load the transcripts
df = pd.DataFrame()

for podcast in os.listdir(path)[0:20]:  # gets transcripts for the first podcast
    podcast_name = podcast
    id = 1

    for episode in os.listdir(path + podcast + '/'):
        episode_name = episode.replace('.txt', '')
        transcript = get_transcripts(path + podcast + '/' + episode)

        temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': [id],
                                       'podcast_name': [podcast_name],
                                       'episode_name': [episode_name],
                                       'transcript': [transcript]},
                                      orient='columns')
    
        df = pd.concat([df, temp], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
        id += 1

df
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also, include a sample of the file that is not being read.

Comment: I can run this script on generic txt files and it works. As @not_speshal says, a sample of a file resulting in NaN values would help to look into this more.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JJdkTFf6x2vHl1nmSweOFMEHMeKnNcw5pivtz_wohTg/edit?usp=sharing

Unable to attach txt file. Kindly refer to drive file

Comment: what character encoding are used by these files? If you are using `open(file_path, 'r')` (text mode), you may need to specify the encoding if not `utf-8`.